# IE scrolling only when cursor is pointing on text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll

I have run to a weird problem. I have a div with position absolute and fixed height and overflow set to auto. And inside is another div, which has bigger height. So in all browsers a scrollbar appears, and in Chrome, Firefox, and IE7 is everything fine. But in IE 8-9 I am able to scroll with mouse, only if the cursor is pointing at some text. When it is pointing on white space, it doesn't respond to mouse scrolling. Does anybody know why is this happening? I trying to create example with this bug, so I'll post it here later.

Comment: Is the inner div a set height too? Does changing the overflow to scroll change anything?

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem in IE8 & 9, see http://jsfiddle.net/REKjt/ .

Comment: changing overflow to scroll doesn't do anything and the height of inner div depends on how long text it contains, so it isn't set. I dont't know, it seems like the inner div is somehow transparent, but when I change background-color to some color, even in IE 8-9it looks exactly how it's supposed to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for responses.
I have managed to solve this. I use jQuery UI dialogs in my application and for registration I have used similar markup as in http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form   As you can see they use `<form />` tag in their code and this tag caused all my troubles. So after removing `<form />` from my code, the scrolling works just fine.